# Facebook read stream permission issue

Tags: facebook, feed

I want permission to read stream of the user so that I can keep track of likes, comments and shares of user post but facebook is not letting me the permission with the reason that "The read_stream permission is only granted for apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. ", but what if I have a facebook app which requires the permission to read stream. pls help

Answer (score 4):

You can´t get `read_stream` approved. period.

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_stream

You can only try to get `user_status` approved and use `/me/statuses` - but you will only get posts of the user that way, not posts of his friends.

**Edit: There is a new permission called "user_posts" that may be sufficient for you, check it out in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3_new_features**

Comment: can we get the time line feed using user_posts permission ?

Comment: just open the last link of my answer and read, the text explains exactly what you get

Comment: user_posts also provides only the posts that you made on your timeline or if some one posts something on your timeline. Except that it does not show the posts made by your friends like check in or some picture uploads